# Android NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: android, nsfetchedresultscontroller, ormlite

I have an iPhone and an Android app. On iPhone I use `NSFetchedResultsController` to manage the data I have for my `UITableView`'s. Currently I have a lot of data (several thousands of rows).

On my Android app i'm using `ORMLite` and i'm storing the data into a table, but when I fetch, i'm pulling out all data into an array and using `ArrayAdapters`. Is there a more efficient way to do this such as an `NSFetchedResultsController` type object? I want to only load the objects needed, rather than all of them for performance reasons.

Is there a way to do this within `ORMLite`? I tried to find in the documentation but found nothing so far... Is there anything else I'm missing that would be of help here?

Answer (score 1):

You could use **CursorAdapter**.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html
and http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html

or you could implement an Endless Adapter

**Lazy Loading** might help here.
Lets presume you have a data of 10000 entries. You could display a finite subset of this say 90 entries at a time.You could initially load a few entries say 30(1-30). On scrolling to the end you load 30 more entries.As soon as the no.of entries loaded reaches 90 (on the third load) you could truncate the current dataset as  31-120 instead of the previous 1-90.

The same goes the other way too i.e on scrolling upwards.

```
int offset=0;
listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
     final int MAX_SUBSET=90;
     final int INTERVAL=30;
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            final int lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;

            if(lastItem == totalItemCount) {
                //Load new data and update The adapter.
                  if(totalItemCount<=MAX_SUBSET){
                      loadData(0,totalItemCount+INTERVAL);
                  }
                  else{
                   offset+=INTERVAL;
                  loadData(offset,MAX_SUBSET);

                   }
            }
            else if(0==firstVisibleItem){
              //Load old data
                if(totalItemCount<=MAX_SUBSET){
                      loadData(0,totalItemCount+INTERVAL);
                  }
                  else{
                   offset-=INTERVAL;
                       loadData(offset,MAX_SUBSET);

                   }
            }
    });
```

Ps: I have missed out a few boundary checks but hope you get the general idea.